# php json:encode returning undefined on http call on angular controller on server but works well on the localhost

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

php json:encode returning undefined on http call on angular controller on server but works well on the localhost.

```
if( hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($password, $hashed_password))){
    $pass = "true";
    $result = array('pass' => $pass, 'FirstName' => $f_name,
    'LastName'  => $l_name,'id' => $id);
}else{
    $pass = False;
    $result = array('pass' => $pass, 'FirstName' => "", 'LastName' => ""
 , 'id' => $id);    
}
$json_response = json_encode($result);
echo $json_response;
```

Comment: Does the console log says anything? If you look on the Network tab of the Developer tools what content is returned from the angular request?

Answer (score 1):

For ajax calls, such as this requires the header to be set as application/json, so javascript can easily read it, and also need to make error reporting to false in ajax related API designs

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
...
...
...
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
echo $json_response;
```

this output is easily readable by javascript

Comment: NOT when developing, no. use error_reporting(E_ALL); and when an error actually occur, fix your code. anyway, OP is probably already error_reporting(0), and don't check json_last_error() and is getting a hidden error..

Comment: your right, but my intention was if there is no error, then json is pure and easily parsed by java-script functions